# Blender 2.62 tutorial for architectural works?

Tags: blender, cad

i just want to learn all staff aboout blender and how to work with it.I am trying to go on linux only and without a windows partition in my system!So i cannot work with autocad in linux also with 3ds max.So i want to work with blender, bricscad and maya.The starting for me will be with blender.So are there any tutorials(complete, step by step) for me to work with precision and dwg importing from brics and then export again etc..

Thanks!

Comment: Packt pub., has many Blender approaches: http://www.packtpub.com/books/all?keys=blender

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd just start using Blender for some project (that's exactly what I did some time ago). Just configure it to have 1 Blender unit == 1 meter (or feet).

There are lots of free tutorials (including video tutorials) all over the Internet - just start doing it and after a while you'll get some speed.

IMO the best way of learning is doing.

Comment: Yeah i think that this is the best choice for me!BUT i have to ask something like how can i import files from bricscad and staff.Things that i do not know!So any help will be great!thanks

Comment: @gabriel, here's a result of a quick googling: http://blendermama.com/importing-2d-cad-files-as-modeling-reference.html

I've never used BricsCAD myself - can't give you any real advices on that.

Comment: Ok, i have already seen that!But really does not help me!I do not know which is the problem!But, even if i manage to do that (i have managed in the past ) the thing that i surely want is importing dwg/dxf and then the polylines are imported, should be ready for extrude with blender!In my experience i have worked with 3ds max and when i import dwg then i dont have to redraw the lines but i am able to extrude or layer them.So, anybody about it? THANKS